# MYSQL get column

Tags: php, mysql, variables, select

There is a table `movie_meta` with columns `meta_id, movie_id, meta_key, meta_value`

I know value of the `movie_id` and want to get value of `meta_value` of the `meta_key` "**links**".

Like we have a row `1|24|links|http://google.com` inside "**movie_meta**"

We make a request for `movie_id` = 24, and get `$link = 'http://google.com';`

**What is a true `SELECT` for this?**

Tryed this, but it gives all the columns:

```
("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE movie_id = 24 AND meta_key = links"")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT *` will return all columns.

To get only the value of `meta_value` use `select meta_value ...`

Full query:

```
SELECT meta_value
FROM movie_meta
WHERE movie_id = 24 AND meta_key = '$link'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
SELECT m.meta_value 
  FROM MOVIES m 
 WHERE m.movie_id = ? 
   AND m.meta_key = 'links'
```

- Strings need to be enclosed in single quotes to be interpreted as such in SQL.
- `SELECT *` returns all columns from the table

PHPified, using [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT m.meta_value 
                    FROM MOVIES m 
                   WHERE m.movie_id = %d 
                     AND m.meta_key = '%s'", 
                  $movie_id,
                  $meta_value)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT meta_value AS link
    FROM movies 
    WHERE movie_id = 24 
        AND meta_key = 'links'
```